# How can I calculate the cluster coefficients of a directed graph in R?

Tags: r, network-analysis

In R, the following code can be used to calculate cluster coefficients.

```
transitivity(g,type = "global")  #"g" is my graph
```

However, this is for undirected graphs and differs from the results obtained by Cytoscape and Gephi.
How can I get the same cluster coefficient values in R for directed graphs as in other software?

Comment: The Global clustering coefficient is same for undirected and directed graph, while the local clustering coefficient is different see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustering_coefficient, you can use R package [DirectedClustering](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DirectedClustering/index.html) to calculate both global and local clustering coefficients.